# Adding CCLabelBMFont to a sprite in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

Lately i have encountered a problem that my program is crashing when i am trying to add BMLabelFont to a sprite

```
CCString *coinLabelString = CCString::createWithFormat("%f",health);
healthLabel = CCLabelBMFont::create(coinLabelString->getCString(), kFontChubby, 0);
healthLabel->setPosition(ccp(winSize.width * 0.525, winSize.height * 0.89));
healthLabel->setAnchorPoint(ccp(0, 0.5));
sprite->addChild(healthLabel, 1);
```

Like this... I am adding the same to game layer and its working.... trying to add it to sprite it crashes with this error

```
Cocos2d: createFontChars : cocos2d::CCLabelBMFont: Attempted to use character not defined in this bitmap: 30584
Cocos2d: createFontChars : cocos2d::CCLabelBMFont: Attempted to use character not defined in this bitmap: 4450
```

this sprite is added to a CCSpriteBatchnode... can it create a problem... anySolution to this problem....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this and check it is working or not                                  healthLabel = CCLabelBMFont::create("Hello", kFontChubby, 0);
healthLabel->setPosition(ccp(winSize.width * 0.525, winSize.height * 0.89));
healthLabel->setAnchorPoint(ccp(0, 0.5));
sprite->addChild(healthLabel, 1);

Comment: been there done that.... i found the error and am working the other way around. The compiler later threw me an error stating CCsprite can only add CCsprites as children when using CCspriteBatchNode

Comment: @UmeshSharma also got that error once when forgot to call parents CCSprite::init()/CCLayer::init() - mb that will help someone